# *.grid() layout manager does not work as I expect it to behave

Tags: python, tkinter

So I try to create my from `Tk.LabelFrame` derived class and use the `grid()` layout manager.
But somehow it doesn't work as expected. It really annoys me, is there anything I dont see?
Every other class I used and created with this method works as expected, but not this one...

This is my minimal working example (which doesnt "work", lol):

```py
# ==[ Import ]============================================================
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import ttk

# ==[ Class definition ]==================================================
class FileHandlingFrame(Tk.LabelFrame):

    # --< Initialization >------------------------------------------------
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure_self()
        self.create_widgets()
        pass

    def configure_self(self):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
        self.pack()
        pass

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Create ui components
        self.importButton = ttk.Button(master=self, text="Import")
        self.exportButton = ttk.Button(master=self, text="Export")
        self.currentLabel = ttk.Label(master=self, text="Current")
        self.createButton = ttk.Button(master=self, text="Create")
        self.configurationButton = ttk.Button(master=self, text="s")

        # Grid components
        self.importButton.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="w")
        self.exportButton.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=4, sticky="e")
        self.currentLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky="w")
        self.createButton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=7)
        self.configurationButton.grid(row=2, column=7, columnspan=1)
        pass

# ==[ Start of main application ]=========================================
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    root.title("MWE")
    mainframe = Tk.Frame(master=root)
    mainframe.pack()
    application = FileHandlingFrame(container=mainframe)
    application.mainloop()
```

This is what I expect:

[image]

But this is what I get:

[image]

Anyone has any idea? I really am fighting this for hours already...

P.S.: I know I should do:

```py
self.importButton.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="w")
self.exportButton.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=4, sticky="e")
```

Comment: Did you try removing `sticky='w'` or try `stricky='ew'`.

Comment: Yes, but still the Button "s" is unproportionally long and not to scale as expected. The Import/Export-Buttons also are not equally large... :(

Comment: Try to create code with reproducible example so we can try it on.

Comment: Alright, I'll update it.

Comment: @CoolCloud Updated the question. Btw you've been active at my question before. Thank you so much!

Comment: I recognize the downvote, but would you please clarify why I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you've given a weight to every column, columns without anything in them will be empty and thus have no size. `weight` only affects how extra space is allocated, and doesn't affect the minimum or default size.

If you want all of the columns to be the same size, you can set the `uniform` option of every column to the same value. It doesn't matter what the value is as long as it is the same for every column.

The other problem is that you aren't using `sticky` properly to get the result from your drawing.

By the way, you can pass more than one column to `columnconfigure`:

```
self.grid_columnconfigure((0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), weight=1, uniform="x")
...
self.importButton.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="ew")
self.exportButton.grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=4, sticky="ew")
self.currentFileLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky="ew")
self.createHeatmapButton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=7, sticky="ew")
self.heatmapConfigurationButton.grid(row=2, column=7, columnspan=1, sticky="ew")
```

Comment: Beautiful, this is exaclty what I needed! Thank you so much!
Is there any way to decrease the size of the buttons and all components? Or are they bound to the smallest element, in this case the "s" button?

Comment: @Sunburst275: if you want the columns the same size, they are bound to the smallest object in one of the columns.